# Get custom category attribute in block Topmenu

Tags: magento2, category-attribute

I have read a lot of topics but none of them seem to help me.

I have created a custom category attribute with a module like so :
**Setup/installData**

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'enable_megamenu', [
            'type'     => 'int',
            'label'    => 'Enable Mega Menu',
            'input'    => 'boolean',
            'source'   => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'visible'  => true,
            'default'  => '0',
            'required' => false,
            'global'   => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group'    => 'General Information',
        ]);
    }
}
```

**view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="enable_megamenu">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable Mega Menu</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now this works , it gets saved in the database and everything.

The next thing is that i need to use the value of that database entry to determine in my Topmenu.php Block if i'm going to change the classes and layout or not.

I have no idea even after reading for a full day how to accomplish this.

**Block code:**

```
<?php
namespace Designit\MegaMenu\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\TreeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{
    protected $categoryFactory;

    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
                                NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
                                TreeFactory $treeFactory,
                                array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $nodeFactory, $treeFactory, $data);
    }


    protected function _getHtml(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
        $childrenWrapClass,
        $limit,
        $colBrakes = []
    )
    {
        $html = '';

        $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
        $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
        $childLevel = $parentLevel === null ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

        $counter = 1;
        $itemPosition = 1;
        $childrenCount = $children->count();

        $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
        $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $child->setLevel($childLevel);
            $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
            $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
            $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

            $outermostClassCode = '';
            $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

            if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
                $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
                $child->setClass($outermostClass);
            }

            if (count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake']) {
                $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
            }

            $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
            $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $this->escapeHtml(
                    $child->getName()
                ) . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                    $child,
                    $childLevel,
                    $childrenWrapClass,
                    $limit
                ) . '</li>';
            $itemPosition++;
            $counter++;
        }

        if (count($colBrakes) && $limit) {
            $html = '<li class="column"><ul>' . $html . '</ul></li>';
        }

        return $html;
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your custom category attribute using below way,

pass your category id instead of 5 in your code,

```
$categoryData = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load(5);
$getContent = $categoryData->getData('enable_megamenu');
```

Remove **var/generation** folder,
Here full code,

```
<?php
namespace Designit\MegaMenu\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Data\TreeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;

/**
 * Html page top menu block
 */
class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{
    protected $identities = [];
    protected $_menu;
    protected $registry;
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
        TreeFactory $treeFactory,       
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {        
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $nodeFactory, $treeFactory, $data);
    }

    protected function _getHtml(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
        $childrenWrapClass,
        $limit,
        $colBrakes = []
    )
    {
        $html = '';
        $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
        $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
        $childLevel = $parentLevel === null ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

        $counter = 1;
        $itemPosition = 1;
        $childrenCount = $children->count();

        /* pass category id */
        $categoryData = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load(5);
        $getContent = $categoryData->getData('enable_megamenu');

        $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
        $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $child->setLevel($childLevel);
            $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
            $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
            $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

            $outermostClassCode = '';
            $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

            if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
                $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
                $child->setClass($outermostClass);
            }

            if (count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake']) {
                $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
            }

            $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
            $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $this->escapeHtml(
                    $child->getName()
                ) . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                    $child,
                    $childLevel,
                    $childrenWrapClass,
                    $limit
                ) . '</li>';
            $itemPosition++;
            $counter++;
        }

        if (count($colBrakes) && $limit) {
            $html = '<li class="column"><ul>' . $html . '</ul></li>';
        }

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what i tried before but every time that i add that         \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
i just get a blank page with error 500. I will see if i can see anything in the logs. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Please remove var/generation folder

Comment: Already a big big thanks for wanting to help me out Rakesh! I have removed it as you asked before i commented. I removed it again just to be sure and it didn't change anything.  I still get a empty page with error 500 : https://demo.versdivers.be/

Comment: Can i cause harm by calling my block the same name as the normal block? di.xml line that changes it :     <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Designit\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmenu" />

Comment: Your block declaration is perfect.

Comment: pleae check your system log or report which error display

Comment: I have added the system.log to the original post. Weird that it does that , if i remove it i do not have that error

Comment: I have added the error.log also now. I think it does not like the parent __construct with the other one. But i'm still learning Magento

Comment: I have fixed those errors by changing         parent::__construct($context, $data);
to         parent::__construct($context, $nodeFactory, $treeFactory, $data);

Comment: I'm editting your post since that is the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62569/discussion-between-swat-be-and-rakesh).

Comment: @CompactCode how we will be able to load category id ?

Comment: @ManishGoswami Do you want to load the category by ID or get the CategoryID?

Comment: If you want the category ID this is done with '$categoryId = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $child->getId());' where your $child is the category object that you want to get the ID from. To load that Category you will need to use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface-->get($id);

Comment: I used this one ----------
$catIdArray = explode('-',$child->getId());
            $categoryData = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load(end($catIdArray));